# Async binding in Aurelia

Tags: promise, aurelia

I'm trying to bind an async value to one of my Aurelia templates, and obviously all I get is `[object Promise]` in return.

I found this article http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-async-bindings/ which excellently explains how to solve this problem using a binding behavior which looks like this:

```
// http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-async-bindings/
export class asyncBindingBehavior {
    bind (binding, source) {
        binding.originalUpdateTarget = binding.updateTarget;

        binding.updateTarget = a => {
            if (typeof a.then === 'function') {
                binding.originalUpdateTarget('...');

                a.then(d => {
                    binding.originalUpdateTarget(d);
                });
            }
            else {
                binding.originalUpdateTarget(a);
            }
        };
    }

    unbind (binding) {
        binding.updateTarget = binding.originalUpdateTarget;
        binding.originalUpdateTarget = null;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when the promise resolves with a string or other non-object-like variable.

But what if my promise resolves with an object? How would I go about accessing the property I need inside that object?

Because if I do: `${object.property & async}` inside my template then it will fail as `object.property` isn't a promise - only `object` is.

I added a bit of a hack that allows me to specify a property as an argument to `async`, like this: `${object & async:'property'}` and updated my binding behavior as such:

```
// http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-async-bindings/
export class asyncBindingBehavior {
    bind (binding, source, property) {
        binding.originalUpdateTarget = binding.updateTarget;

        binding.updateTarget = a => {
            if (typeof a.then === 'function') {
                binding.originalUpdateTarget('...');

                a.then(d => {
                    if (property) {
                        binding.originalUpdateTarget(d[property]);
                    }
                    else {
                        binding.originalUpdateTarget(d);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                binding.originalUpdateTarget(a);
            }
        };
    }

    unbind (binding) {
        binding.updateTarget = binding.originalUpdateTarget;
        binding.originalUpdateTarget = null;
    }
}
```

But this feels very much like a hack to me, and it also won't allow me to access any deeper properties like `object.parent.child`.

I also found this (rather old) issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/81 where they use a `getValue` method. I've never heard of this method and trying to use it fails so I'm not sure how that works at all...

Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tested it myself but... https://github.com/zewa666/aurelia-async-binding

Comment: Actually I came here looking because there is another problem with the asyncBindingBehavior class you posted (and I use the same one, but am about to change it): There exists a race condition between bind and unbind. Specifically if the async bind is still pending resolve, and unbind happens, then `originalUpdateTarget` will be `null` once the promise is resolved and `a.then(...` tries to call `binding.originalupdateTarget(d)` resulting in an exception ("originalupdateTarget is not a function"). So a null-check is needed inside `a.then` to ensure originalUpdateTarget hasn't been unbinded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sidestep your conundrum by specifying a function as the third parameter, giving the flexibility to do much more than simple property extraction.

You could write something like this :

```
export class asyncBindingBehavior {
    bind (binding, source, transformer="default") {
        binding.originalUpdateTarget = binding.updateTarget;
        binding.updateTarget = a => {
            if (typeof a.then === 'function') {
                binding.originalUpdateTarget('...');
                a.then(d => binding.originalUpdateTarget(transformFunctions[transformer](d)));
            } else {
                binding.originalUpdateTarget(a);
            }
        };
    }
    unbind (binding) {
        binding.updateTarget = binding.originalUpdateTarget;
        binding.originalUpdateTarget = null;
    }
}
```

The `transformFunctions` lookup would be necessary(?) due to the way Aurelia bindings are specified as HTML-ebbedded or template directives (ie all params must be String). Unless Aurelia offers a better way better way to "pass a function" ([Value Converters](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-value-converters)?), you would write something like this :

```
export var transformFunctions = {
    default: (d) => d,
    transform1: (d) => d.someProperty,
    transform2: (d) => d.someProperty.someOtherProperty,
    transform3: someFunction,
    transform4: someOtherFunction.bind(null, someData);
}
```

*Of course, you would give the functions better names.*

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean. I guess a function would make more sense as I could do whatever I want to extract the value I need. But is this really the best way to do this? Ideally I'd _love_ something like `${object.property & async}`. Perhaps I could "walk" up to `object` from the `property` somehow??

Comment: For sure, you could pass a "dot.separated.property.string", `.split('.')` it then drill down associatively to extract `d["dot"]["separated"]["property"]["string"]` but that's certainly less flexible than function(s) and arguably more messy.

Comment: Alright, I'll leave this question open for a little while longer to see if I get any more suggestions.

Comment: Like you, I'm interested to know if there's a better way.